# How to send CosmosDB dependency tracking data to Application Insights from Azure Function Event Hub Trigger

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-application-insights, azure-eventhub

I have an Azure Function that is triggered by eventhub and sends data in batches. Inside function, there are multiple calls to insert data into CosmosDB. I have added following code as part of `App Insight` Monitoring.

```
 builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

            builder.Services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>((module, o) =>
            {
                module.EnableW3CHeadersInjection = true;
            });

         
            builder.Services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<EventCounterCollectionModule>(
                    (module, o) =>
                    {
                        module.Counters.Add(new EventCounterCollectionRequest("System.Runtime", "gen-0-size"));
                    }
                );
```

I can see total response time in App Insight but cannot figure out how to track and send time spent by each insert query in `CosmosDB`

Here is `C#` code within Azure Function

```
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    
                    var DemoContainerData = new
                       {
                           id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                           UserId = userId,
                           // other properties 
                       };

                       _demoContainer.CreateItemAsync<object>(DemoContainerData);
                       
                       var DemoContainerData2 = new
                       {
                           id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                           ProductId = productId,
                           // other properties 
                       };

                       _productContainer.CreateItemAsync<object>(DemoContainerData2);
              /* var dependency = new DependencyTelemetry
               {
                   Name = "",
                   Target = "",
                   Data = ",
                   Timestamp = start,
                   Duration = DateTime.UtcNow - start,
                   Success = true
               };
               this._telemetryClient.TrackDependency(dependency);
               */                    
            watch.Stop();
            var elapsed = watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            log.LogInformation("Total Items {0} - Total Time {1}", Items.Length, elapsed);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not awaiting the async operations, you should be:

```cs
ItemResponse<object> response = await _demoContainer.CreateItemAsync<object>(DemoContainerData);
```

From the response, you can measure the client latency:

```cs
var elapsedTimeForOperation = response.Diagnostics.GetClientElapsedTime();
```

What we recommend if you want to investigate high latency is to log the Diagnostics when the request goes above some threshold, for example:

```cs
if (response.Diagnostics.GetClientElapsedTime() > ConfigurableSlowRequestTimeSpan)
    {
        // Log the diagnostics and add any additional info necessary to correlate to other logs 
        log.LogWarning("Slow request {0}", response.Diagnostics);
    }
```

For best latency, make sure you are following https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/troubleshoot-dot-net-sdk-slow-request?tabs=cpu-new#application-design (mainly make sure you are using a Singleton client, use `ApplicationRegion` or `ApplicationPreferredRegions` to define preferred region to connect which hopefully is the same region the Function is deployed to).

Comment: Thanks mate. that's really helpful and it worked. I deployed these changes to azure and I could see individual query response time for multiple inserts within the batch. at present there are 4 inserts within single iteration of for loop and to speed up the processing with more throughput this code is now changed from sequential for loop to parallel for loop. next step is to calculate time for all inserts within entire batch for example if there were 1000 events in the batch then time for all inserts query needs adding up. not sure whether I need to use thread safe shared variable or collection

Comment: If you have a high volume of changes you might want to consider bulk mode: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-bulk-support-in-the-net-sdk/

Comment: we are in the process of getting some figures from client but most likely several thousand events per second with < 1 second latency in processing the batch would be  minimum requirement